# How to get all results on the Github API

Tags: python, github-api

I am a new coder in Python, and I am trying to extract the most starred projects in the category "python" on Github. Unfortunately, it does not give me all the results, and thus giving me incorrect information.

What I have in my code is this:

```
import requests

# Make an API call and store the response.
url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars"
headers = {"Accept": 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(f"Status code: {r.status_code}")

# Store API response in a variable.
response_dict = r.json()
print(f"Total repositories: {response_dict['total_count']}")

# Explore information about the repositories.
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']
print(f"Repositories returned: {len(repo_dicts)}")

# Examine all of the repos.

print("\nSelected information about each repository: ")
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    print(f"Name: {repo_dict['name']}")
    print(f"Owner: {repo_dict['owner']['login']}")
    print(f"Stars: {repo_dict['stargazers_count']}")
    print(f"Repository: {repo_dict['html_url']}")
    print(f"Created: {repo_dict['created_at']}")
    print(f"Updated: {repo_dict['updated_at']}")
    print(f"Description: {repo_dict['description']}")
```

Now, while searching on Github, I know that the most starred project is vinta/awesome-python. But whenever I run this code, the first value is this:

```
Name: Auto-GPT
Owner: Significant-Gravitas
Stars: 145932
Repository: https://github.com/Significant-Gravitas/Auto-GPT
Created: 2023-03-16T09:21:07Z
Updated: 2023-08-08T00:39:08Z
Description: An experimental open-source attempt to make GPT-4 fully autonomous.
Name: Python-100-Days
Owner: jackfrued
Stars: 138354
Repository: https://github.com/jackfrued/Python-100-Days
Created: 2018-03-01T16:05:52Z
Updated: 2023-08-08T01:09:10Z
Description: Python - 100天从新手到大师
```

On the API Github page, I found why it didn't work:
`incomplete_results = true`.
But what I don't know is how I could fix this. Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

Dplicate of [Github API incomplete_results for a simple search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885108/github-api-incomplete-results-for-a-simple-search)

As with APIs which can provide a lot of responses, they provide pagination support in order to retrieve all the data requested.

Here specifically the request supports "page" query argument (see https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#search-repositories), so I suggest that you iterate the search request and aggregate the responses until you stop receiving a response (eg:4xx status code or empty "items", or "incomplete_results" is False). I don't see any other safer option.